# Xfinity coaxial Cable ->Arris Router -> Unmanged switch -> Google Home Wifi Router And Raspberry Pi 4, Pi has no internet

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I am using an Arris SB 6190 to receive internet from Cable (Xfinity) as input.

Then I use one ethernet cable connect from Arris to Netgear 8-Port Gigabit Ethernet Unmanaged Switch (GS308) - Home Network Hub.

Then I have 2 outs from Netgear 8 port. One out is to my Google Home WiFi, which works. One out is to Raspberry Pi 4. This one get's no internet.

eth0 on Raspberry Pi 4 is `169.254.x.x` indicating DHCP is not working.

I also replaced the Raspberry Pi 4 with my old Windows laptop, also no networking.

Is that the issue from my switch?

Comment: Does the Arris do routing? There's a lot 'strange' here with the set up, but is your google home wifi getting a public IP from the Arris? I'm guessing it got it 'first' - and its a miracle that's working at all. Try Arris -> router -> switch -> other stuff

Comment: "Does the Arris do routing?" -- I am not exactly sure.


"Arris -> router -> switch -> other stuff"  --- my "Google - Wifi - Mesh Router" has only one port, which is used as input from Arris. So this suggestion is not possible given current hardwares.

Comment: Well - *logically* - your setup shouldn't work at all, and its slightly baffling that it does

Comment: Your modem only has one network port. Your Google Wifi got it. You need to use a router instead of that switch, and then it should all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modem is a pure modem, *not* a modem router, so its not assigning IPs out. There's also nothing doing nat and/or routing - and its a slight mystery why this works at all with the google home wifi with the switch inbetween. I've seen unmanaged switches pass through/work slightly unusually, but its a black box and I've no idea how to divine its workings.

Your google home wifi probably also does routing, and your cable modem does not. It is a *little* strange that the google home wifi is grabbing an IP *first*  - but here's generally what I *think* is happening. Its grabbing an IP, making requests to the modem, and the modem's going all 'oh ok, there's ONLY one thing connected'. That's speculation though.

You *need* a router in between to take the network connection from the modem and send it to the appropriate machines *and* to handle local IP addresses.

Basically your setup *shouldn't* work at all, and that it works even a little bit is mysterious.  What *will* work needs extra hardware, but that's how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just clarify a couple things.

1. Raspberry PI is connected from the Switch. Not "Google - Wifi - Mesh Router"
2. I have checked the model of my Arris Modem. it has routing mechanism.  (Arris SB 6190 ) 
3. What I want to achieve is,
1) Google home continue working,, to provide WIFI to my devices at home.
2) I need an physical ethernet cable working for my Raspberry PI 4.
What device should I buy now?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd stick a cheap router between the modem and everything else. Borrowing or scrounging one up to test would be wise if you're not sure before deciding to buy one. It'll also do what the switch is doing *and* the google home device so it also simplifies the topology a bit